# My program is only using the default values from my class GeometricObject instead of the user input

Tags: java, inheritance, default-value

I'm currently learning about inheritance in java. I have a class GeometricObject:

```
public class GeometricObject {
    private String color = "white";
    private boolean filled = false;

    /**Default construct*/
    public GeometricObject() {
    }

    /**Construct a geometric object*/
    public GeometricObject(String color, boolean filled) {
        this.color = color;
        this.filled = filled;
    }

    /**Getter method for color*/
    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    /**Setter method for color*/
    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    /**Getter method for filled. Since filled is boolean,
     so, the get method name is isFilled*/
    public boolean isFilled() {
        return filled;
    }

    /**Setter method for filled*/
    public void setFilled(boolean filled) {
        this.filled = filled;
    }

}
```

And then I have a class Triangle that extends GemoetricObject:

```
import static java.lang.Math.sqrt;

public class Triangle extends GeometricObject{
    double side1 = 1.0;
    double side2 = 1.0;
    double side3 = 1.0;

    public Triangle(){
        super();
    }

    public Triangle(double side1, double side2, double side3, String color, boolean isFilled){
        super(color,isFilled);
        if (side1 <=0||side2 <= 0||side3 <= 0) {
            System.out.println("Sides must be greater than 0!");
        }

        if (side1 > (side2 + side3)||side2 > (side1 + side3)||side3 > (side1 + side2)) {
            this.side1 = side1;
            this.side2 = side2;
            this.side3 = side3;
            System.out.println("Invalid side lengths!");
        }
    }

    public double getSide1(){
        return side1;
    }

    public double getSide2(){
        return side2;
    }

    public double getSide3(){
        return side3;
    }

    public double getArea(){
        double s = (side1 + side2+ side3) / 2;
        return sqrt(s*(s - side1)*(s - side2)*(s-side3));
    }

    public double getPerimeter(){
        return side1 + side2 + side3;
    }

}
```

When I go to run the program, it runs fine. Perimeter and area all work. But, instead of outputting the values the user inputs, the program is outputting "The white triangle is 1.0 X 1.0 X 1.0." So it's only using the defaulted values, but I'm honestly not sure why

EDIT: Here's my main function, can't believe I forgot that:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PA6 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Triangle t = new Triangle();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter side 1: ");
    double side1 = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter side 2: ");
    double side2 = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter side 3: ");
    double side3 = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter a color: ");
    String color = input.nextLine();
    input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Is it filled? ");
    boolean fill = input.nextBoolean();
    input.nextLine();


    System.out.println("The " + t.getColor() + " triangle is " + t.getSide1() + " X " + t.getSide2() + " X " + t.getSide3());
    System.out.println("Area: " + t.getArea());
    System.out.println("Perimeter: " + t.getPerimeter());
    System.out.println("Filled? " + t.isFilled());
}

}
```

Comment: Offhand, this looks OK. Could you share the snippet where you create the `Triangle` instance?

Comment: @Mureinik I edited the post and added my main function, for some reason I forgot it when I made the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is here:

Every side of triangle should be **smaller** than other two sum. So your `>` should look right. Operator `||` (OR) should be also changed to `&&` (AND).

```
if(side1 < (side2 + side3) && side2 < (side1 + side3) && side3 < (side1 + side2)){ 
    this.side1 = side1;
    this.side2 = side2;
    this.side3 = side3;

} else {
    System.out.println("Invalid side lengths!");
}
```

UPD:

Use `next()` instead of `nextLine()`

```
String color = input.next();
```

And delete extra  `input.nextLine();`

Comment: Hey, thanks! Don't know what I was thinking when I wrote that. I started this a couple of days ago and that part is now fixed!

Comment: @ANewProgrammer mark this question correct please if it solved your problem. Or write me if not

Comment: I'm still having trouble in my main function. I'm passing my user input to the constructor Triangle t = new Triangle (side1,side2,side3,color,fill); And while the sides and fill are all being tracked correctly, it's not even outputting the default value of white

Comment: @ANewProgrammer what does it output?

Comment: it outputs nothing at all. When I do System.out.println("Color: " + t.getColor()), it outputs Color:, and then nothing afterwards

Answer (score 0):

You use a Scanner to input data from the user, but you never pass this data to the `Triangle`'s constructor. Once you're done with the user input, just pass those variables as arguments to the constructor:

```
Triangle t = new Triangle(side1, side2, side3, color, fill);
```

Comment: So I did that, but now nothing is being outputted when I call t.getColor(). Not even the default value white is being outputted. Everything else is working perfectly though as expected.